# Change time variable from HH:MM format to HHMM in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset `flex` in which one of the columns - Bookings - includes hours and minutes HH:MM. I need to remove the dots to have instead HHMM.
I tried:

```
gsub(":", "", flex$Bookings)
```

but this returns all new changed variables in the console, the variables in the dataset do not change.
I also tried:

```
flex$Bookings<-gsub(":", "", flex$Bookings)
```

but nothing happens. I know I miss something simple but can not figure out what. Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you actually looked at `flex` after to check?! Try `head( flex$Bookings )`....

Comment: I did not. Just checked. The dots are not there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am confused by your question. Please take a look at this output.

```
flex <- data.frame(Bookings = paste0(10:20, ":", 20:10))
flex$Bookings <- gsub(":", "", flex$Bookings)

flex
#    Bookings
# 1      1020
# 2      1119
# 3      1218
# 4      1317
# 5      1416
# 6      1515
# 7      1614
# 8      1713
# 9      1812
# 10     1911
# 11     2010
```

Your syntax, for the question you asked, is correct.

Another option, if you table is very large, is to use the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
flex_dt <- data.table(Bookings = paste0(10:20, ":", 20:10))
flex_dt[ , Bookings := gsub(":", "", Bookings)]
```

Comment: I am playing now with a small dataset, but when ready will be working on a  large dataset, so thanks for your advice. Will try the data.table package.

Comment: I recommend using `gsub(":", "", flex$Bookings, fixed = TRUE)`. This is faster if you don't need a regular expression (as the default uses).

Comment: Roland, can you explain why using fixed=TRUE is better. I tried it and have not seen the difference. Could you explain what you mean be 'regular expression'? Thanks anyway for your advice

Comment: From the documentation: `"If you are doing a lot of regular expression matching, including on very long strings, you will want to consider the options used. Generally PCRE will be faster than the default regular expression engine, and fixed = TRUE faster still (especially when each pattern is matched only a few times)."`

Comment: You're welcome! It will help you get more attention in the future to accept correct answers to your questions. You can do so by clicking the little check-box under the number. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

This might be too slow for you, but you could consider using a POSIX class, and format.Date.

```
time1 <- c("14:08")

time1.date <- format.Date(as.POSIXct(time1, format="%H:%M"), format="%H%M")
```

Again, this might be pretty slow, but if your need is specific to date/times, and you don't need a lot of speed, this approach could be helpful to you. Good luck.